# Double update problem all my row data column disappear

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I have table in phpmyadmin, I update its row value from a word to a different word. My code line is :

```
UPDATE database213
SET category = COALESCE((
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(Category_Name)
    FROM categoryinfo
    WHERE FIND_IN_SET(Category_Code, REPLACE(database213.category, ' ', ''))
), '');
```

Why when I double update it one more time the category data row all disappear

I tried to search for a fix online couldn't find one. This is very important for me because when I keep getting data need to import and update them the category column that have word codes like IAB24 which represent sports category.

By the way there is lots of codes that is why I put a different table of category code and category names to replace my main category column in my main table.

Comment: The first time you run this statement, it's going to try to turn interpret whatever is in `category` as a comma separated list of `Category_Code` values and transform this into a comma-separated list of `Category_Name` values.  When you run the statement a second time, it's again to going to try to interpret whatever is in `category` as a comma separated list of `Category_Code` values - but it isn't (because they are `Category_Name` values) so it doesn't match any categories, hence everything is set to an empty string.  All of which should be telling you that a link table would be much better

Comment: [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad) *(Spoiler alert: The answer is yes)*